# C++ days passed from last check

Tags: c++, date, date-difference

I wanted to create a program that keeps track of the last time the user watered the plants (manual check). So basically... The user presses a button and the program set today's date as date1, then every day it updates date2. If the difference is bigger than a certain date, the program returns a string.

```
int main() {
  int time_elapsed = ; \\???
  std::cout << needs_water(difference) << "\n";
  
}
```

Here's the main function, and the called function is the following:

```
std::string needs_water(int days) {
  if (days > 3){
    return("Time to water the plant.");
  }
  else {
    return("Don't water the plant!");
  }
}
```

Sorry for my bad English and thanks in advance.

Edit: In a few words what I want to know is how to tell the program how much time elapsed from the last check.

Comment: You explained what you want to do, so far so well. Whats the question?

Comment: Are asking what to replace `difference = date2 - date1` with? Then you need to specify your date format.

Comment: Well, it seems like you will need to figure out how to (1) get the current date and time, (2) store the current day and time, (3) read back the stored day and time, and (4) compare them to see how many days apart they are.  Does that help?

Comment: If the program will exit you will likely have to store this time value in a file.

Comment: You don't even seem to have the code for getting the current time, so why do you start with the second step and think about how to calculate the time difference? Wouldn't it be better to go step by step (with the steps that Tumbleweed53 described).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example that should do what i understood you want to achieve. Replace `milliseconds` with `days` (c++20) or with `hours`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

using namespace std::chrono;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

template<typename DurationT>
bool time_elapsed(DurationT time) {
  static auto last_check = steady_clock::now();
  auto now = steady_clock::now();
  auto time_passed = now - last_check;
  if (time_passed > time){
    last_check = now;
    return true;
  }
  else {
    return false;
  }
}

int main()
{
    for(int i=0; i < 12; ++i) {
        std::cout << (time_elapsed(milliseconds{3}) ? 
            "Time to water the plant!" : 
            "Don't water the plant!") << std::endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(1ms);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9e3600759ed902c2

Comment: This answer could be improved by not exiting the chrono type system with `.count()`.  It would improve the type-safety, readability and ease of maintainability of the code.  `auto time_passed = now - last_check;  if (time_passed > days{3}) ...`

Comment: @HowardHinnant thanks! Improved the answer based on your input, using a more generic template now.

Comment: Does removing the `duration_cast` change the behavior of the function?  Why or why not?

Comment: @HowardHinnant no, it's a superfluous duration_cast to the same duration type. Forgot to remove it in the first edit your comment pointed that out exactly. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

> how to tell the program how much time elapsed from the last check.

Either have your program running all the time. That way, you can store all the data in programs memory.

But if the program is meant to be run and then exit, then you obviously need an **external** entity to store the **state**. That is typically a simple file in some constant location below users home directory.

For example get current time and save it in some form to a file in a constant location. The simplest that "form" would be seconds since... some constant time - typically since [epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(computing)). Then upon program startup, see if the file exists, if it does, read the last time. Then get current time since epoch - the difference between the value stored in the file and current time will be how much time has passed.